# Rebinding pedals to buttons AHK

Tags: autohotkey, joystick

I am using a Thrustmaster TMX PRO. I want to use AHK to change my pedals to a button. Right now i have this

```
SetTimer, WatchAxis, 5
return

WatchAxis:
JoyThrottle := GetKeyState("JoyX")  ; Get position of X axis.
JoyBreak := GetKeyState("JoyY")  ; Get position of Y axis.
KeyToHoldDownPrev := KeyToHoldDown  ; Prev now holds the key that was down before (if any).
JoyInfo := GetKeyState("JoyInfo") 
;MsgBox, %JoyInfo%
if (JoyBreak > 45)
    KeyToHoldDown := "Down"
else if (JoyThrottle > 45)
    KeyToHoldDown := "Up"
else
    KeyToHoldDown := ""

if (KeyToHoldDown = KeyToHoldDownPrev)  ; The correct key is already down (or no key is needed).
    return  ; Do nothing.

; Otherwise, release the previous key and press down the new key:
SetKeyDelay -1  ; Avoid delays between keystrokes.
if KeyToHoldDownPrev   ; There is a previous key to release.
    Send, {%KeyToHoldDownPrev% up}  ; Release it.
if KeyToHoldDown   ; There is a key to press down.
    Send, {%KeyToHoldDown% down}  ; Press it down.
return
```

This works for the break pedal but doesn't work for the throttle.So i have tried the following:
`GetKeyState(Joy+"X","Y","Z","RX","RY","RZ","SL0","SL1","R","Z","P","D"` (all of them seperate ofc)

Without result. My problem now is finding the button. To find the throttle I tried the following:

`JoyInfo := GetKeyState("JoyInfo") MsgBox, %JoyInfo%`

This showed:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea to help me forward?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have one controller that has analog inputs for L2 and R2. Both act as the sum of each other. Pressing only L2 moves the axis to 100. Pressing only R2 moves the axis to 0. Pressing both with about the same force makes the sum 50.

Comment: By the way "PD" are not 2 axis, it means Discrete-POV. To get that value you have to use "JoyPOV".

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but the issue now for me is that i cant catch the throttle yet with the AHK code but i can catch the break and convert it to a button press

Comment: There is this script that it's a bit outdated in its syntax but maybe it can help you get a picture of how things are behaving https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/JoystickTest.ahk

Comment: @scso could you put this as answer it helped me fix my script very usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for me to understand controllers has been with this script:

(It's a bit old, modern ahk syntax doesn't usually look so much like that, but it still works.)

```
; Joystick Test Script
; https://www.autohotkey.com
; This script helps determine the button numbers and other attributes
; of your joystick. It might also reveal if your joystick is in need
; of calibration; that is, whether the range of motion of each of its
; axes is from 0 to 100 percent as it should be. If calibration is
; needed, use the operating system's control panel or the software
; that came with your joystick.

; July 6, 2005: Added auto-detection of joystick number.
; May 8, 2005 : Fixed: JoyAxes is no longer queried as a means of
; detecting whether the joystick is connected.  Some joysticks are
; gamepads and don't have even a single axis.

; If you want to unconditionally use a specific joystick number, change
; the following value from 0 to the number of the joystick (1-16).
; A value of 0 causes the joystick number to be auto-detected:
JoystickNumber = 0

; END OF CONFIG SECTION. Do not make changes below this point unless
; you wish to alter the basic functionality of the script.

; Auto-detect the joystick number if called for:
if JoystickNumber <= 0
{
    Loop 16  ; Query each joystick number to find out which ones exist.
    {
        GetKeyState, JoyName, %A_Index%JoyName
        if JoyName <>
        {
            JoystickNumber = %A_Index%
            break
        }
    }
    if JoystickNumber <= 0
    {
        MsgBox The system does not appear to have any joysticks.
        ExitApp
    }
}

#SingleInstance
SetFormat, float, 03  ; Omit decimal point from axis position percentages.
GetKeyState, joy_buttons, %JoystickNumber%JoyButtons
GetKeyState, joy_name, %JoystickNumber%JoyName
GetKeyState, joy_info, %JoystickNumber%JoyInfo
Loop
{
    buttons_down =
    Loop, %joy_buttons%
    {
        GetKeyState, joy%A_Index%, %JoystickNumber%joy%A_Index%
        if joy%A_Index% = D
            buttons_down = %buttons_down%%A_Space%%A_Index%
    }
    GetKeyState, JoyX, %JoystickNumber%JoyX
    axis_info = X%JoyX%
    GetKeyState, JoyY, %JoystickNumber%JoyY
    axis_info = %axis_info%%A_Space%%A_Space%Y%JoyY%
    IfInString, joy_info, Z
    {
        GetKeyState, JoyZ, %JoystickNumber%JoyZ
        axis_info = %axis_info%%A_Space%%A_Space%Z%JoyZ%
    }
    IfInString, joy_info, R
    {
        GetKeyState, JoyR, %JoystickNumber%JoyR
        axis_info = %axis_info%%A_Space%%A_Space%R%JoyR%
    }
    IfInString, joy_info, U
    {
        GetKeyState, JoyU, %JoystickNumber%JoyU
        axis_info = %axis_info%%A_Space%%A_Space%U%JoyU%
    }
    IfInString, joy_info, V
    {
        GetKeyState, JoyV, %JoystickNumber%JoyV
        axis_info = %axis_info%%A_Space%%A_Space%V%JoyV%
    }
    IfInString, joy_info, P
    {
        GetKeyState, joyp, %JoystickNumber%JoyPOV
        axis_info = %axis_info%%A_Space%%A_Space%POV%joyp%
    }
    ToolTip, %joy_name% (#%JoystickNumber%):`n%axis_info%`nButtons Down: %buttons_down%`n`n(right-click the tray icon to exit)
    Sleep, 100
}
return
```

Found here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/index.htm#JoystickTest

Comment: this helped me find the corresponding axis aliases to write an ahk so i can rebind my pedals to arrow keys cheers!